# Can I make my chrome extension perform an action on an URL that doesn't resolve?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Basically I want my extension to add a page, for example when you enter extension.test it should show a page I created, instead of making a search with the default search engine.

I used to do this with webapps, but those were removed.

Comment: When the user types in the addressbar Chrome sends search queries so you can use webRequest API and parse/analyze the URL.

Comment: [chrome.omnibox API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox)?